# Pandas - How to replace a single quotation mark followed by a comma ( ", )

Tags: python, pandas, csv, replace

I have a text file that looks like this:

```py
,Symbol,Date"+
",DRI,23/04/2021"+
",CQN,28/04/2021"+
",TGG,29/01/2021"+
```

and I want the result that looks like this:

```py
"Symbol,Date"+
"DRI,23/04/2021"+
"CQN,28/04/2021"+
"TGG,29/01/2021"
```

I'm using pandas to convert csv to the text file above but I got this single double quote with comma right after (",) that I want to replace with only one single double quote (").

In the code below:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(in_csv, na_filter=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

    # dict of replacements
replacements = {
    '"",': '"'
}

    # using the replace() method
df1 = df.replace(replacements, regex=True)
```

I tried many possible solutions like

```py
1. '\"' to '"' 
2. """," to """"
3. '\""," to '"'
...
```

but none seems to work. Doing this with Find and Replace in notepad is easy, but I need to automate this task by using code only.
I'm also stuck at how to remove only that first comma and the last (+) sign without affecting the rest.

Could you suggest a solution to this problem I'm having?

Comment: You could read the file, write to a list, truncate the file, make changes and then write to the file again.

Comment: @sean-william pls try not to use html tags in every sentence you write. It make the post not only difficult to read but also looks immature. You want to emphasize something ensure its only the most specific item that needs absolute attention.

Comment: I thought it looks easier to read than just plain text :( I will look into this

Comment: @Sujay Thank you for your suggestion. I'm trying to see if it works for me

Answer (score 1):

No need for pandas here. The file is not a csv file but a plain text file so you could just use:

- the `re` module to change the beginning of the lines and the end of a last line. Compiling the regex before looping over the lines is slightly more efficient
- the common *read and write on temporary file* pattern commonly used to modify text files. Keeping the previous line is a simple way to easily identify the last line.

It could be:

```
import re
import os

infile = 'ess.txt'
tmpfile = infile + '.tmp'

# pre-compile the regular expressions
init = re.compile(r'^"?,')
last = re.compile(r'"\+\s*$')

with open(infile) as fd, open(tmpfile, 'w') as out:
    old = None
    for line in fd:
        if len(line.strip()) == 0:  # skip empty lines
            continue
        if old is not None:
            out.write(old)
        old = init.sub('"', line)
    out.write(last.sub('"\n', old))

os.remove(infile)
os.rename(tempfile, infile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a pattern with a lambda to do the replacement, and load the string using `StringIO`

If group 1 is present (the last plus sign) then return an empty string. Else return a double quote.

```
^"?,+|(\+)\Z
```

- `^` Start of line
- `"?,+` Match an optional double quote and 1 or more comma's
- `|` Or
- `(\+)` Capture a plus sign in **group 1**
- `\Z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UNmf47/1)

For example

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open('file', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read()
    pattern = r"^\"?,+|(\+)\Z"
    data = re.sub(pattern, lambda m: "" if m.group(1) else '"', lines, 0, re.MULTILINE)
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), na_filter=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    print(df)
```

Output

```
      Symbol,Date+
0  DRI,23/04/2021+
1  CQN,28/04/2021+
2   TGG,29/01/2021
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I guess I need to brush up on my regex more!

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to non-python solutions, `sed` can do this job easily :)

```sh
sed -e 's/^",/,/g' -e 's/^,/"/g' -e '$ s/+$//g' test.txt
```

1. `'s/^",/,/g'` replaces the first line starting `",` with `,`
2. `'s/^,/"/g'` replaces all starting `,` by `"`.
3. `'$ s/+$//g'` removes the `+` sign on the last line, at end of line. `sed` has the concept of addresses and `$` means the last line.

On some systems, you might have to use `sed -i -e`.